# Optimize/vectorize a loop in R that generates randoms from ranges in input vectors?

Tags: r, loops, vector, vectorization, genetic-algorithm

**Problem:**

I am using a loop in R to create a new vector from two ("parent") vectors, generating a random value for each position in the new vector that is in the range of the values that the parents have in this position (it's for the crossover phase in a [genetic algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Genetic_algorithm)). Note that I don't want the mean values of x & y, but namely random values that are in range of the values on the respective positions.

**Example code:**

```
x = c(0.1, 0.7, 1, 0.8)
y = c(0, 0.9, 0.2, 1)
child = rep(NA, length(x))
for(i in 1:length(x)){
  child[i] = sample(seq(min(x[i], y[i]),  
                        max(x[i],y[i]), by=0.01), 1)
}
# This might yield, for example: 0.02 0.83 0.73 0.88
```

**Question:**

It works fine, but I'm thinking maybe there's a more efficient way to do this (since I need to do this for 100-1000 individuals on each of the thousands of iterations). 
In R, there are nice fast functions like `ifelse`, `colMeans`, `max.col`, [`match`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24157876/vectorizing-loop-over-vector-elements), [`rollmean`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1886264/avoiding-loops-in-r?rq=1), etc., that work on vectors, so I'm wondering, is there's something like that for my purposes as well? (the `apply` gang probably wouldn't help much here though, from what I understand). Or is a loop like this really the best I can do?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

We can use `runif` to get random numbers from a uniform distribution, and `pmax` and `pmin` to vectorize the min and max:

```
round(runif(length(x), pmin(x, y), pmax(x, y)), 2)
```

A small benchmark:

```
library(microbenchmark)

set.seed(42)
x <- runif(1000)
y <- runif(1000)

microbenchmark(vectorize ={round(runif(length(x), pmin(x, y), pmax(x, y)), 2)},
               mapply =  {mapply(runif, 1, pmin(x, y), pmax(x, y))},
               lapply = {unlist(lapply(seq_along(x), function(p, q, i) { sample(seq(min(p[i], q[i]), max(p[i],q[i]), by=0.01), 1) }, p=x, q=y))})

Unit: microseconds
      expr       min        lq       mean     median        uq       max neval cld
 vectorize   316.417   321.026   341.6501   336.0015   342.914   529.154   100 a  
    mapply  4311.559  4429.640  4733.0420  4543.6875  4806.535  9935.631   100  b 
    lapply 46987.459 47718.980 50484.6058 48474.5015 53599.756 60043.093   100   c
```

Comment: @ jeremycg: `res <- round(runif(length(x), pmin(x, y), pmax(x, y)), 2); table(pmin(x,y)<=res); table(pmax(x,y)>=res)` showed some values are outside the range...surprisingly.

Comment: @fishtank its rounding error - eg the `p(min x, y)` might be 0.232, and the random number we got is 0.234, which gets rounded to 0.23, and we are out of range. In this case, op is only using 2 digits as input, so doesnt need to worry (more broadly, don't round to lower than your input).

Comment: The rounding part is not necessary anyway; I just had simple "short" numbers in the example to keep it, well, simple. Besides being a good answer, it's always nice to see comparisons to the previous "state of the art".

Answer (score 4):

Here's an `mapply` solution:

```
mapply(runif, 1, pmin(x,y), pmax(x,y))
```

(Although @jeremycg's solution shows that you don't need *apply functions and can just vectorize the min and max for `runif` as well.)

Answer (score 3):

Here's a data.table solution with 10 million records in 2 seconds:

```
library(data.table)
set.seed(4444)
n <- 10000000
system.time({
  dt <- data.table(x=runif(n=n,min=0,max=10),y=runif(n=n,min=0,max=10))
  dt[,child := runif(n=n,min=pmin(x,y),max=pmax(x,y)),by=.I]
})
dt

#user  system elapsed 
#2.01    0.03    2.06
```

Comment: Also a good idea. But I choose @jeremycg's answer, as it seems more suited for my purposes (the vectors in the example is pretty much what I'm working with).